# Is Forcing only possible in first-order theories?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, forcing

I'm trying to understand forcing in set theory. From what I understood it necessary that the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem holds to extend models or to force extensions. So, is forcing only possible in first-order theories?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [Here](https://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/scott67.pdf) is a paper by Dana Scott that proves the independence of CH in a higher order theory of the reals instead of the first order theory ZFC. The approach taken is by Boolean valued models.

Comment: What makes you think the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem is relevant? Forcing extensions are completely different from the kind of extensions you get from the proof of Löwenheim-Skolem. Sometimes people might appeal to Löwenheim-Skolem in order to obtain a countable model to force over. But this is not really necessary, and it's in the setup, prior to the actual forcing construction.